# Problem installing S3FS on the RHEL 6 system

Tags: rhel6, s3fs

We're trying to move off a physical RHEL 6 server, with the help of some S3 storage. I'm following the special RHEL 6 install process call out in the [install instructions](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/wiki/Installation-Notes). The fuse 2.8.4 install appears to work but when I try to install s3fs it appears to fail.

Is there some other steps I need to make sure are installed, other then those in  the install instructions?

```
s3fs-fuse]# ./configure --prefix=/usr --with-openssl
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking sys/xattr.h usability... yes
checking sys/xattr.h presence... yes
checking for sys/xattr.h... yes
checking attr/xattr.h usability... no
checking attr/xattr.h presence... no
checking for attr/xattr.h... no
checking sys/extattr.h usability... no
checking sys/extattr.h presence... no
checking for sys/extattr.h... no
checking s3fs build with nettle(GnuTLS)... no
checking s3fs build with OpenSSL... yes
checking s3fs build with GnuTLS... no
checking s3fs build with NSS... no
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for common_lib_checking... yes
checking compile s3fs with... OpenSSL
checking for DEPS... yes
checking for malloc_trim... yes
checking for library containing clock_gettime... -lrt
checking for clock_gettime... yes
checking pthread mutex recursive... PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE
checking checking CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE... no
checking checking CURLOPT_SSL_ENABLE_ALPN... no
checking checking CURLOPT_KEEP_SENDING_ON_ERROR... no
checking for git... yes
checking github short commit hash... e2fbcb4
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating test/Makefile
config.status: creating doc/Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing depfiles commands

s3fs-fuse]# make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/s3fs-fuse'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/s3fs-fuse/src'
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/usr/local/include/fuse -I/usr/include/libxml2      -g -O2 -Wall -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -MT s3fs.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/s3fs.Tpo -c -o s3fs.o s3fs.cpp
mv -f .deps/s3fs.Tpo .deps/s3fs.Po
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/usr/local/include/fuse -I/usr/include/libxml2      -g -O2 -Wall -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -MT curl.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/curl.Tpo -c -o curl.o curl.cpp
curl.cpp: In member function ‘bool BodyData::Resize(size_t)’:
curl.cpp:198: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
curl.cpp:199: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
curl.cpp:200: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
curl.cpp:201: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
curl.cpp:202: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
curl.cpp:205: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
mv -f .deps/curl.Tpo .deps/curl.Po
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/usr/local/include/fuse -I/usr/include/libxml2      -g -O2 -Wall -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -MT cache.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/cache.Tpo -c -o cache.o cache.cpp
mv -f .deps/cache.Tpo .deps/cache.Po
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/usr/local/include/fuse -I/usr/include/libxml2      -g -O2 -Wall -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -MT string_util.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/string_util.Tpo -c -o string_util.o string_util.cpp
mv -f .deps/string_util.Tpo .deps/string_util.Po
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/usr/local/include/fuse -I/usr/include/libxml2      -g -O2 -Wall -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -MT s3fs_util.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/s3fs_util.Tpo -c -o s3fs_util.o s3fs_util.cpp
mv -f .deps/s3fs_util.Tpo .deps/s3fs_util.Po
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/usr/local/include/fuse -I/usr/include/libxml2      -g -O2 -Wall -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -MT fdcache.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/fdcache.Tpo -c -o fdcache.o fdcache.cpp
fdcache.cpp: In static member function ‘static bool PageList::GetSparseFilePages(int, size_t, fdpage_list_t&)’:
fdcache.cpp:478: error: ‘SEEK_HOLE’ was not declared in this scope
fdcache.cpp:479: error: ‘SEEK_DATA’ was not declared in this scope
fdcache.cpp: In static member function ‘static bool PageList::CheckZeroAreaInFile(int, off_t, size_t)’:
fdcache.cpp:518: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
make[2]: *** [fdcache.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/s3fs-fuse/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/s3fs-fuse'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

s3fs master branch requires a newer kernel and glibc:

https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/issues/1354

You can work around this by compiling s3fs 1.86 instead.

Comment: Using the s3fs version 1.86 worked great, thanks for the tip. I did this all about a year ago a a few machines and this was driving me in circles.